# Flask-Blogging: Error: Table [...] doesn't exist, (tables not being created)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add Flask-Blogging to an existing app, but it doesn't seem to want to play nice with the existing Flask-SQLAlchemy MySQL database. It works fine using its own sqlite database however.

On app startup, it tries to create the tables (every time), and doesn't give an error:

```
flask run
 * Serving Flask app "myapp"
 * Forcing debug mode on
2017-06-13 21:32:33,369:DEBUG:flask-blogging:Created table with table name post
2017-06-13 21:32:33,371:DEBUG:flask-blogging:Created table with table name tag
2017-06-13 21:32:33,373:DEBUG:flask-blogging:Created table with table name tag_posts
2017-06-13 21:32:33,375:DEBUG:flask-blogging:Created table with table name user_posts
2017-06-13 21:32:33,472:INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However, accessing the blogging route complains (correctly) that the table doesn't exist. Looking in the database they aren't there.

Here's the relevant code:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    db.init_app(app)

    migrate = Migrate()
    migrate.init_app(app, db=db)

    # Required to prevent Flask-Blogging messing with existing tables
    from app.models import User, Product, Purchase

    # Flask-Blogging database config
    with app.app_context():
        storage = SQLAStorage(db=db)
        blog_engine = BloggingEngine()
        blog_engine.init_app(app, storage)
```

`config` is a config object contains the relevant sql connection string (in `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`) as well as other required Flask configuration variables, and is working fine for the rest of the app.

Comment: Hmm. Sure sounds like the Flask-blogging is using its own config/connection object.

Comment: @ShawnMehan That is not accurate. New connections are created only if necessary.

Comment: @Matt Can you also provide the `SQLAlchemy` and `Flask-SQLAlchemy` versions you are using? Your implementation seems correct and is supported feature in `Flask-Blogging`.

Comment: Nothing better than having the maintainer answer the appropriate question! Superb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demonstrating the dangers of cut-and-paste programming (where you don't actually understand what the code does), I was missing:

```
db.create_all()
```

Shame SO doesn't let you delete embarrassingly stupid questions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`Flask-Blogging` uses the `db` to get the `metadata`. There may be some interaction that we are missing here. Can you try explicitly setting `metdata` for the database object and blogging's storage?

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

metadata = MetaData() #
db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=metadata)
...
db.init_app(app)
...
storage = SQLAStorage(db=db)
# or
#storage = SQLAStorage(engine=db.engine,  metadata=metadata)
...
```

Comment: I was missing `db.create_all()`. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thanks for jumping in, and thanks for sharing Flask-Blogging!